# How to get SortedSet to update position of old value?

Tags: python, sorting, sortedset, sortedcontainers

I have the following object that I would like to keep in a container that is sorted on insertion and does not contain duplicates, so I am using a `SortedSet`

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet, SortedList


class R():

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.person_id)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__class__ == other.__class__ and self.person_id == other.person_id

    def __nq__(self, other):
        return not (self == other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return other.value < self.value

    def __init__(self, person_id, value):
        self.person_id = person_id
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "person: %s (%s)" % (self.person_id, self.value)

x = SortedSet()

x.add(R(13, 2))
x.add(R(17, 4))
x.add(R(11, 21))
x.add(R(7, -41))

print(x)
```

When I run this code I get the following output as expected:

> SortedSet([person: 11 (21), person: 17 (4), person: 13 (2), person: 7 (-41)])

However if I added an extra duplicate element i.e. 17:

```
x.add(R(13, 2))
x.add(R(17, 4))
x.add(R(11, 21))
x.add(R(7, -41))
x.add(R(17, -67))

print(x)
```

I expect the R object with id 17 named `person: 17 (4)` to be moved to the back with value `person: 17 (-67)` like:

> SortedSet([person: 11 (21), person: 13 (2), person: 7 (-41), person: 17 (-67)])

However nothing changes:

> SortedSet([person: 11 (21), person: 17 (4), person: 13 (2), person: 7 (-41)])

How can I achieve the desired output as described using a `SortedSet` or any other container that is sorted on insertion and has no duplicates?

Comment: Side-note: You typoed the `__ne__` method, but you didn't need it in the first place, so don't fix the typo, just delete the whole method (your implementation was subtly incorrect in any event, and the default `__ne__` you get on Python 3 is implemented properly in terms of `__eq__` without the subtle misbehavior you've got).

Comment: What exactly do you need the container to support? Anything other than adding `R` objects and printing (i.e., conversion to string)?

Comment: Or is what you really want maybe a *dictionary* with your ids as keys and your values as values, sorted by values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DeepSpace's answer covers making this work (if somewhat inefficiently)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467113/364696), but I'm going to issue a frame challenge here: This is a bad design.

Sets (the logical construct) are designed to store unique items. If something `add`ed to a set is equal to something already in it, there's no reason to replace the old item, because the old item and the new item are *equivalent*. If your class does not use a definition of equality in which equality implies substitutability (two equal instances could be use interchangably in all relevant ways), then the instances aren't suitable for use in a `set`. Even without `SortedSet` getting involved, using plain `set`, this wouldn't work, because `set.add` won't replace an item when you insert an "equal" item; they're both equivalent after all, so why do the extra work?

When you need to have a concept of keys that can map to values, where the values for a given key can be changed later without knowing the original value, you want a mapping (`dict`-like), not a set (`set`-like).

[Kelly Bundy suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72466936/how-to-get-sortedset-to-update-position-of-old-value#comment128017378_72467113) that what you want may already exist in the `sortedcollections` package (`ValueSortedDict`), so I'd go with that if it works. Since `sortedcontainers` contains nothing that allows replacing values *and* sorting on the values, you'd have to go to a *lot* of work to add that behavior, roughly the same order of magnitude as implementing it yourself from scratch.

---

##### Additional notes on why this doesn't work:

On top of your use case being fundamentally unsuited to sets (the logical concept, not merely `set` itself), `SortedSet` itself is unusually inappropriate for your class, because implicitly relies on two invariants (only one of which is strictly required by Python, though the other is *usually* adhered to):

1. Required by Python: `__eq__` should be consistent with `__hash__`: If two items are equal, they *must* have the same hash, and, as much as possible, two unequal items should *not* have the same hash (ideally the hash should be based on the same fields `__eq__` compares, but it's legal to base it on a subset of those fields)
2. Required by SortedSet (and often assumed by other things that work with sorted objects): `__eq__` should be consistent with `__lt__` (and all other rich comparison operators): If `a == b`, then `a < b` and `b < a` should both be false; similarly, if `a < b` or `b < a` is true, then `a != b`. Most sorting stuff in Python sticks to `__lt__` comparisons exclusively to allow inconsistent definitions, but if you stick the same objects in a `tuple` for comparisons, suddenly the lexicographic ordering rules means `tuple`'s own `__lt__` implementation relies on both the `__lt__` and `__eq__` of your class, so in practice you want them consistent anyway.

Your class violates #2; the sorting rules are *completely* unrelated to the definition of equality. `SortedSet` muddles along here, determining uniqueness based on `__hash__`+`__eq__` and ordering with `__lt__`, but in certain circumstances (e.g. when removing elements) it relies on `__lt__` being consistent with `__eq__`. Specifically, after removing from the internal `set` (using `__hash__`+`__eq__`_) it then removes from the internal `SortedList`, which bisects to find the element to remove, using `__lt__`, and confirms it found the right element with an equality check, using `__eq__`. Since `__eq__` and `__lt__` are inconsistent (they'd only match if you were trying to remove an `R` with the same `person_id` and `value`), this never finds the value it's trying to remove, and it raises an exception.

Comment: ValueSortedDict was the way to go. Cheers and thanks for the explainer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `SortedSet`, overriding its `add` and `remove` methods. We need to override `remove` because the original implementation uses `self._list.remove` which will fail because the two `R` objects will not be identified as equal.

```py
class MySortedSet(SortedSet):
    def add(self, value):
        if value in self:
            self.remove(value)
        super().add(value)

    def remove(self, value):
        self._set.remove(value)
        for index, e in enumerate(self._list[:]):
            if hash(e) == hash(value):
                self._list.pop(index)
                break


x = MySortedSet()

x.add(R(13, 2))
x.add(R(17, 4))
x.add(R(11, 21))
x.add(R(7, -41))
x.add(R(17, -67))

print(x)
```

outputs

```
MySortedSet([person: 11 (21), person: 13 (2), person: 7 (-41), person: 17 (-67)])
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the response but I was hoping if there was a better solution then o(n) for the remove method

Comment: "will not be identified as equal" sounds wrong. If they get compared for equality, they should be identified as equal. Are they just not compared for equality, due to the ordering?

Comment: `sortedcollections.ValueSortedDict` might be helpful, with keys being just the ids and values being either their `R` objects or just their values. (I'm on a phone, too inconvenient to try it myself)

Comment: @Tom: The linear `remove` is necessary because the *only* sublinear lookup available on the `SortedList` wrapped by `SortedSet` is based on the `value`, and when you're inserting a *new* item with a given `person_id`, you don't know the old `value`, just the new one. There's no way to make a `set` report the value currently stored in it that equals something else (if you have a value you could use to look it up with, you don't *need* the value in the `set`, because you've got something equivalent), so unless the user of the class keeps the old value separately, you're stuck.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Actually, I think there *is* an O(1) way to get the old value from the set, given the new value. Just ask whether the new value is in the set, and have the `__eq__` method catch the old value during the comparison.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Eew. Clever, but eew. Could probably be made to work with arbitrary values with a custom-wrapper class that delegates to the underlying object's `__hash__` and `__eq__`, and just caches when the `__eq__` is about to return `True`, which does make it practical for arbitrary objects, but still, eew. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I can agree with "ew" :-). Maybe not quite arbitrary objects, though. I actually tried something like that, but it didn't work because it's the `__eq__` of the *old* object (the one in the set) that's called.

Comment: @DeepSpace Why the `[:]`? I don't think you need that.

Comment: @KellyBundy: It wouldn't work with `R` as written, because `R`'s `__eq__` is implemented improperly (it returns `False` on a type-mismatch, when it should return `NotImplemented` in that situation to cause the comparison machinery to ask the right-hand side whether it knows how to do the comparison). Correct solution would be something like `return self.person_id == other.person_id if isinstance(other, R) else NotImplemented`. I'm okay with only supporting properly written classes when I say "arbitrary". :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy An habit to not remove an element from a list while iterating it. I agree that it is not needed here since we `break` because we assume it contains unique elements.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, when I realized that it doesn't even allow the reflected call and didn't see another path, that's when I gave up on the "wrapper" idea without modifying the `R` class. Besides `new in x` I also tried `x.intersection([new])`, hoping it might call the comparison the other way, but it didn't (and no, the intersection result sadly doesn't contain the old but the new value, otherwise that's what I would've suggested instead).